# How to delete all words that contain apostrophes in Sublime Text 3

Tags: grep, sublimetext3

I have a word list of over 10,000 words, but this is just a sample:

```
'Tis midnight
sev'n words spoke
th'Immortal night
A wonder-working pow'r
Wondrous deliv'rer to me
```

I want to delete all words that contain apostrophes so the list should look like this:

```
midnight
words spoke
night
A wonder-working
Wondrous to me
```

How can I do this using Sublime Text so it finds apostrophes and smart apostrophes (`’`)?

Comment: You might match `\S*['’]\S*\h*` and replace with an empty string https://regex101.com/r/u9q6rL/1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a character class`['’]` to match both variations of the apostrophes and match zero or more times a non-whitespace character `\S*` before or after the matched apostrophe followed by optional horizontal white-space chars.

```
\S*['’]\S*\h*
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/u9q6rL/1)

---

A slightly more optimized version without preventing the first `\S*` causing backtracking could be using a [negated character class](https://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html#negated) `[^\s'’]*` to match until the first apostrophe.

```
[^\s'’]*['’]\S*\h*
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/jwovCa/1)